# What is the symbol ######## in a .csv file?

Tags: csv, github

I am looking at the data from [this](https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/data/blob/master/police-deaths/clean_data.csv) github page and I noticed some weird behavior:

[image]

Some of the data cells are filled with ########, but when I click on them I can see a date at the top, as outlined in red. These symbols do not seem to appear in the raw data; yet when I save it on my computer the issue appears (I've tried saving it multiple times and the issue still appears)

This is the raw data:

[image]

Jailer Alfred Henry is the one that I have selected in the first picture.

The way I save it onto my computer is by going to the raw data page, right click, and then clicking "Save as..."

Can somebody please shed some light on why this is happening, and if there is a way to fix it?

If possible, I would very much like to keep it as a .csv file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the column width is not enough to show a number/date it is displayed as ######## . Just increase the width of column

Answer (score 3):

Its because of the content size is larger than the column width. Please go through this [Change the column width and row height](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-column-width-and-row-height-72f5e3cc-994d-43e8-ae58-9774a0905f46) in order to arrange the data properly into each row and column.